# c++ pointing to array of char

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;



int main(){

char s[10] = "abcde"; 

char* first = s - 1;

cout << first << endl;

return 0;
}
```

when I run this, I get a blank in my console, but when I say *first = s; I get the whole char array printed to my console. My question is, what exactly is first pointing to when I set it to s - 1?

Comment: `char* first = s - 1` points to garbage?

Comment: This is UB. The reason you're seeing the whole array is because you forgot to add \0 at the end of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set a pointer to `s-1`, the pointer points to a character at a position in memory that is one `char` before your allocated string. Dereferencing such pointer is undefined behavior - the program may print anything, or even crash.

Comment: @user2510809 Correct - undefined behavior is a wrong thing to do. Programs that invoke undefined behavior are considered invalid.

Answer (score 0):

`first` would point to a piece of unallocated memory - the behavior is undefined